# XenServer 6.2 not forwarding ports to VMs

Tags: port, xenserver

I have a XenServer 6.2 with OVH with 4 additional IP addresses.

For 2 VMs that are installed all is working fine.

I created now a new VM with CentOS 6.6, added the virtual MAC OVH assigned me for the IP and setup the network interface accordingly.

I can connect without problem to SSH on port 22, but all other traffic (like port 80 for apache2) is not reaching the VM.

I already disabled selinux.

Same for example when i switch SSH port from 22 to let's say 51000 it's also not working any more.

What can be the problem with that?

The problem started to appear after i setup a VM with CentOS 7 on this XenServer 6.2.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      954/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1186/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1091/mysqld
tcp        0      0 167.114.58.46:80            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1917/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      954/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1186/master
```

Comment: You need iptables to forward the 22 to some port from host to VM. Me to tried this but fails, finally we own fail-over IP to assign for VMs

Comment: http://help.ovh.co.uk/Proxmox

Comment: have you READ what i wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. We had a CentOS Distro where when installing the httpd server it was not automatically adding the rules to the iptables.